# Multi Controllers in one view Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am starting to learn RoR and have been doing a range of tutorials but have hit a stumbling block regarding having a range of controllers in one view. E.g. I have a User controller and a Skill Controller. Skill is associated to the User using belongs_to and has_many skills ect. I am on the index of the user view and cant work out how to put the skills associated with the user into that view.

The way I see it is i will need to create a method that calls the database based on a value. How can i call this method inside the view? Sorry if this seems obvious to some people but I am just getting to grips with it and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm doing rails apps, I tend to have **one** controller to **many** views, not the other way round.

What I think you want is two methods in your controller which point to the same view. To achieve this, in the method that isn't named the same as your view, call `render "view"`. Or, if both the methods have different names from your target view, call render "view" in both of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <h2><%= user.name %> </h2>
    <h3>Skills</h3>
    <ul>
        <% user.skills.each do |skill| %>
            <li> <%= skill.name %> </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Now you have users and skills being show at your index page.

Comment: unfortunately it failed. Probably me not explaining what i was developing. I have generated a scaffold called user that has all user details and skills is a scaffold containing user_id. Each have their own views ect but woudnt mind combining them if possible

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are adding non-REST resources in your users controller.

what you should be doing is create a controller for a combination of models, for example a dashboard controller, the trick is to find a name that makes sense. In your case you might have to create a UserSkill controller.

This way you will keep the 5 REST actions.